# Will the conditional method call with no code be included in the output file?

Tags: delphi, conditional-statements, file-io

I have 3 questions, but they are hard to describe, so I've put them into the code:

```
// 1. will this method be included in the output exe file when
// there is a call for it but the LOG_ENABLED is not defined ?
procedure LogSomething;
begin
  {$IFDEF LOG_ENABLED}ShowMessage('Something is logged');{$ENDIF}
end;

// 2. will this method be included in the output exe file when
// there is no call for it ?
procedure LogSomething2;
begin
  ShowMessage('Something is logged');
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // 3. will this method call be included in the output exe file 
  // when this method has no executable code (because LOG_ENABLED 
  // is not defined) ?
  LogSomething;
end;
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: RTTI settings are relevant here

Comment: @David - I have Delphi since 2007 to XE2 ? Is there an universal recipe how to configure it for the similar code fragments elimination ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603650

Comment: I don't mean to be contrarian or combative, but my question for you is, "Why would you care about this?"  Is this the most significant place you can find to work on to optimize the size or speed of your application, or (as I suspect) is this more a case of pre-mature optimization? http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil

 (PS Having just upgraded to XE2, I'm trying out Codesight and am delighted to use it rather than ShowMessages, OutputDebugStrings, or the like.  I should have tried Codesight a long time ago.)

Comment: @RobertFrank - you're right, I might use some sofisticated logging system, and I know it's just nothing from the preformance and file size point of view but still I'm wondering why the compiler can't do this optimization without `inline`.

Comment: @Martin Presumably compiler designers decided to expend their efforts on optimisations and developments that would bring greater reward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, although it may be inlined and disappear
2. If it's not visible outside the unit (for example, being exported as a DLL function), then no, the compiler saves space by not including unused functions into the executable
3. Maybe, the compiler could optimise the call away when it sees that the function doesn't do anything

`$IFDEF` is used to modify the text of the source file before the compiler sees it. When you use `$IFDEF` in the first method and `LOG_ENABLED` is not defined, the method looks like this to the compiler

```
procedure LogSomething;
begin

end;
```

When it *is* defined, it looks like this

```
procedure LogSomething;
begin
  ShowMessage('Something is logged');
end;
```

Comment: Thank you, so in assembler will this be just `ret` for empty method and `call` for the method call as usually ? I was hoping that this might get optimized in the compiler (if the called method is empty then I would ignore the whole method and all of its calls).

Comment: @MartinReiner yes, though again the compiler is free to optimise that away so that if you look at the assembly, it is as if the function never existed and never was called.

Comment: I think I don't get your last comment, so it won't be linked in the output exe file or will be there as a `call LogSomething` and `ret` if I execute the program ?

Comment: @MartinReiner if the function does nothing, it is a waste of time to call it. So if the compiler is optimising, it will see that it is a waste of time to call that function, and completely remove the call. If the compiler sees that no functions call that function (whether it is because no functions made any calls to it, because all the calls were removed by the optimiser, because all the calls were inlined, or whatever), it will not be linked in to the executable.

Comment: Not as waste as it seems, you know, I have my code editor very colorful and the code like `{$IFDEF LOG_ENABLED}ShowMessage('Something is logged');{$ENDIF}` at every line I want to log is just disturbing me. I would like to call only `LogSomething;` where I will have the conditional defined code for logging but I don't want this call nor the method code to be linked to the target exe file.

Comment: @MartinReiner no, I mean it would be a waste for the computer to call a function that doesn't do anything (in your case when `LOG_ENABLED` is not defined, the compiler might optimise the call away because it sees that it does nothing. Function calls take time and the compiler will add speed by not doing things that do nothing but waste time, such as calling functions that do nothing).

Answer (score 2):

You can check it yourself by trying to set a breakpoint on the lines under question and seeing if a breakpoint is valid. The answer can depend on compiler optimization settings, for Delphi XE with default settings the answers are yes, no, yes.

Comment: Thanks, yes the breakpoint is valid, but I'll be glad to optimize it, so the compiler won't link the emty code methods and its calls to the output exe. I'm working on Delphi 2007 now and there I was hoping for compiler `Optimization` option.

Comment: @Martin - I guess the compiler can't do it now.

Comment: @Martin - If you inline 'LogSomething' compiler does not produce the call and ret for your test case, it doesn't inline anything either.

Comment: @Sertac - If you call `LogSomething` from other unit the compiler generally can't guaranty that the function will be inlined; Delphi Xe  compiler issues a warning in such cases.